# Can't seem to use custom font in React Native Android Emulator

Tags: android, react-native, fonts

Followed standard tutorials on how to add custom font in React Native.

Steps that I did when I got the error:

1. Put the font file in `./assets/fonts` ==> `./assets/fonts/JUST Sans Regular.ttf`.
2. Grabbed the name (`'JUST Sans Regular.ttf'`, `'JUST Sans Regular'` didn't work) and used it as the fontFamily.
3. Web emulator works, android studio emulator gives error:

```
fontFamily "JUST Sans Regular.ttf" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.
```

4. Proceed to install `expo-font`
5. `Font.loadAsync` gives error

```
ERROR
TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.

WARNING
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 17):
Error: Downloaded file for asset 'JUST Sans Regular.ttf' Located at http://127.0.0.1:19000/assets/assets/fonts/JUST%20Sans%20Regular.ttf?platform=android&hash=3ebc4e4e5f59d44574963a8c1c8ee880?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false failed MD5 integrity check
```

react-native.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios:{},
        android:{}
    },
    assets:['./assets/fonts/'],
}
```

Job component I'm using the custom font in:

```
export default function Job() {
  const [loaded] = Font.loadAsync({
    'JUST Sans Regular': require('../../assets/fonts/JUST Sans Regular.ttf'),
  });
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

return (
      <Text
        variant="headlineMedium"
        style={{ marginHorizontal: 18, marginTop: 5, fontFamily: 'JUST Sans Regular.ttf' }}
      >                                                           // tried JUST Sans Regular as well, both don't work
        Job Information
      </Text>
    )
}
```

I also tried the `npx react-native-asset` command to link the assets. So it works in the web emulator, but not in the Android Studio emulator. Why am I using the Android Studio emulator? Because I need `DateTimePicker` which is not supported by the web emulator.

File structure:

```
|   .gitignore
|   App.js
|   app.json
|   babel.config.js
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   react-native.config.js
|            
+---assets
|   |   adaptive-icon.png
|   |   favicon.png
|   |   icon.png
|   |   splash.png
|   |   
|   \---fonts
|           JUST Sans ExBold.ttf
|           JUST Sans Regular.ttf
|           
+---node_modules
|   |   .package-lock.json
\---src
    \---screens
        |   Home.js
        |   Job.js
        |   TotalStats.js
        |   
        \---general
                Models.js
                Styles.js
```